# CakePHP 2.0 File Upload

Tags: mysql, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

Hi I want to create a file upload system that will enable me to upload videos (even just a basic file upload system that can be modified easily), I've looked around and there isn't enough clear tutorials, or tutorials that use an MySQL table as I want to store information about the video, such as a custom Name and Description.

Was wondering if anybody would be willing to point me into the right direction...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not seen any built in file upload helpers before, but you can just do a standard form with:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array('type' => 'file'));
```

as the file field and use

```
move_uploaded_file($this->data['Model']['field']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.DS.'xxx');
```

in the controller to move it to where you want.